# Simple CUDA kernel with Bizarre Result?

Tags: arrays, matlab, visual-studio-2012, cuda

I am using a CUDA kernel object in MATLAB in order to fill a 2D array with all '55's. The result is very strange. The 2D array only fills up to a certain point as shown below. After row 1025, the array is all zeros. Any idea what could be going wrong?

[image]

Comment: I think you should change `masterForces[globalIdx * r_max + i]` to `masterForces[globalIdx * iterations + i]`. Each thread serves one matrix row, while the number of columns is provided by `iterations`. So the offset from one row to the next one should be `iterations`.

Comment: A JPEG is not an acceptable way to post code. I have inlined the image, but please post the kernel code in the question as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment above, you are mistakenly offsetting the matrix rows. The code below is a full working example proving this point.

```
#include<thrust\device_vector.h>

__global__ void myKern(double* masterForces, int r_max, int iterations) {

    int threadsPerBlock = blockDim.x * blockDim.y;
    int blockId         = blockIdx.x + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.x);
    int threadId        = threadIdx.x + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x);
    int globalIdx       = (blockId * threadsPerBlock) + threadId;

    //for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) masterForces[globalIdx * r_max + i] = 55;
    for (int i=0; i<iterations; i++) masterForces[globalIdx * iterations + i] = 55;

}

void main() {

    int ThreadBlockSize = 32;
    int GridSize        = 32;

    int reps            = 1024;
    int iterations      = 2000;

    thrust::device_vector<double> gpuF_M(reps*iterations, 0); 

    myKern<<<GridSize,ThreadBlockSize>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(gpuF_M.data()),reps,iterations);

    int numerrors = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<reps*iterations; i++) { 
        double test = gpuF_M[i]; 
        if (test != 55) { printf("Error %i %f\n",i,test); numerrors++; }
    }

    printf("Finished!\n");
    printf("The number of errors is = %i\n",numerrors);
    getchar();

}
```